# MS Lists - Lookup

Tags: lookup-column, microsoft-teams, mslists

I have a Microsoft Team "Department Name", with a few channels within it.
General > Holds a 'List' for all Customers and their respective ID numbers ('Customer Name' and 'Customer ID') named "Customer List".

I have created a new List within a different channel (Department Name>Channel-123) named "Asset Register".

I have looked at using 'Lookup' in the 'Customer Name' column of the newly created List "Asset Register".

- It can see "Customer List"
- I can select "Customer Name" as the column to select
- I can then save it.
  --- The Customer ID is the same column format (Number), and both contain the same Customer ID's.

The 'Customer Name' column adds in, but does not show any data.

What am I missing? Is there something I need to do to 'tell' it to 'If CustID=123 in List 1 & List 2, display the Customer Name'?

Thanks